# Vodafone network blocking API (Chrome)?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile

I have a website which uses my own backend API service for login (JSON Api over HTTPS Connection). I realized few days ago that **on some** mobile devices the login is not working because the backend API service cannot be reached. This only happens on Chrome/Opera but Firefox works fine. The problem also only appear when the device is on a mobile network. When connected to wi-fi everything works fine again.

The concerned devices seems to all have vodafone network. So, it might be connected to that. The website is for office usage so it is 100% legal and should not be blacklisted.

What I tried without any success:

1. I cleared all Browser Data of Chrome
2. I entered the ip of the backend service directly in the browser to rule out any dns resolve issues
3. Lite-Modus of chrome is disabled

I would be grateful about any ideas/advices.

I will also contact Vodafone support to see if they can help.

Comment: If FireFox does it than the provider is not blocking i would think.

Comment: Where does your server reside? And the backend api?

Comment: You said the server can be reached but not the backend api which is used by that server?

Comment: @blackapps Both frontend and backend are on AWS servers. But they are on different servers/ips. Frontend can be reached. Backend not. Both are on a HTTPS connection. It still seems to be the chrome/vodafone combination. I can create a mobile hotspot with a phone which is not working. Then connect a Laptop to that hotspot. And again on that Laptop with Chrome I cannot login. But with Firefox on that Laptop login works. Really wired.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with the combination Vodafone Network + Chrome 78/79 + TLS 1.3. Not sure the exact reason but switching to TLS 1.2 fixed the Problem temporary. Also the issue is not available in Chrome 80.

Also in this thread [Http Connection Timeout only when mobile client surfing from vodafone network + google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890375/http-connection-timeout-only-when-mobile-client-surfing-from-vodafone-network) someone hinted that it is an issue with Java 11 which we use. We will retest the issue when we update to a newer Java Version.